# Connect to database with kerberos

Tags: asp.net, wcf, active-directory, kerberos

I have the following problem:
On my client, i call a `asp.net` site which connects to my `IIS` with a `WCF`. I pass my `Active Directory` user from the client and then from `IIS`, i try to connect to the `SQL-Server` (on the same machine as the `IIS`).
Until here everything works fine! But when i try to get a connection to the database with the AD-user, I get an `EntityCommandExecutionException`:

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0

with the Inner Exception

> Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid

I really don't know how to handle this or what to set up in `IIS` or some `web.config`
 to pass this user to database.
Maybe someone knows how to solve this specific problem?

**EDIT:**
Here is the Web.config for the WCF-Client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws2007Binding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          transactionFlow="false" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://server/service/Service.svc"
        binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Service.IService"
        name="ws2007HttpBinding_IService">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="MSSQLsvc/server:1433" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and this one is for the WCF-Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>        
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <ws2007HttpBinding>
        <binding name="ws2007Binding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          transactionFlow="false" >
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007HttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="ws2007HttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Server;initial catalog=Database;integrated security=False;User Id=user;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Now i access the database once with the user in the `Web.Config` where everything works fine, but when i try to delegate my AD-User and then connect to database i get an exception:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public List<string> GetInfo(string text)
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var someTempInfos = db.Infos.Find(text); //<-- EntityCommandExecutionException
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code that illustrates what you're doing? You have a Kerberos Constrained Delegation issue here and/or permissions on the host most likely.

Comment: @BrianDesmond I updated my question, i hope it's a little bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it working. i just forgot to set the Impersonation Level to `Delegation`. So the solution is to set the Impersonation Level in the (client-)method after creating the service:

```
    var service = ServiceFunctions.GetService();

    if (service.ClientCredentials != null)
        service.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
                           TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar error and I was able to fix it by disabling the Shared Memory Provider, forcing the SQL client to use TCP/IP. In a production environment you'd almost never have SQL server on the same machine anyway so I suspect that's why this error doesn't occur much there.